# Is there anywhere to post proofs?

Tags: proof-writing

I devised a neat proof that the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval is $0$. I was immediately tempted to post it to math stack, but feared it would frowned upon as it is not a question. Therefore, I was hoping to find out if there *was* a place to post non-question based things like a proof.

On another note, if anyone is interested, her is my proof:

Note first that:
$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x) \, dx$$
In the case of a symmetric interval, this reads:
$$\int_{-a}^a f(x)\,dx = \int_{-a}^a f(a-a-x)\,dx = \int_{-a}^a f(-x) \, dx$$
In the case of an odd function, $f(-x) = -f(x)$, so that
$$\int_{-a}^a f(x) \, dx = -\int_{-a}^a f(x) \, dx$$
The only way that a positive number can equal a negative number is if the number is $0$.  QED

Comment: How else is this proved?

Comment: That's a pretty standard proof.  However, you could post a question and then post the answer to it. $\qquad$

Comment: The first time it was introduced to me, it was displayed graphically/conceptually, so there was no formal proof provided. The next time, it was displayed using u-substitution where $x = -u$. I haven't see this method before, though I understand it's really not much a stretch from the u-sub method, and is unlikely to be *original.* My question is more-so regarding the policy on math stack for a place to post proofs.

Comment: A blog seems like a good place for this sort of thing.  Or the old fashioned version, a journal.

Comment: Thank you, Michael, that helps greatly!

Comment: If you aim to ask whether your proof is correct or not, we have the [tag:proof-verification] tag for questions.

Comment: [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page) is one place to post proofs.